# Spring datagrid with checkboxes

Tags: java, spring, datagrid, spring-mvc

I have a web-application in spring where tasks should be assigned to workers (say programmers).

1. the application should be able to list tasks (unassigned tasks) in a grid
2. On another side, the application should list workers (say programmers)
3. the manager should be able to choose select tasks (or checking), and choose workers to whom he/she wishes to assign selected tasks
4. hit submit button to assign selected tasks to chosen workers.

Now, form processing with spring is processed `onSubmit(..., Command command, ...)` by binding a command (in most of cases Model classes) to the form. How can I implement the functionality above,  given 2 lists (one for workers and another for tasks). I appreciate any idea, link to a resource or a link to the same question as mine.

Comment: Thanks Skaffman, you made my question more understandable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that values of checked checkboxes with similar names can be bound as array:

```
<form ...>
    Tasks:
    <c:forEach var = "task" items = "${tasks}">
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "taksIds" value = "${task.id}"> ${task.title}
    </c:forEach>

    Workers:
    <c:forEach var = "worker" items = "${workers}">
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "workerIds" value = "${worker.id}"> ${worker.name}
    </c:forEach>
</form>
```

-

```
class Command {
    private long[] taskIds;
    private long[] workerIds;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks axtavt for the answer, if i got it well, you are suggesting to have an array of objects in such a way 

<code> 

MyController extends SimpleFormController {

...

private Task[] tasks; 
private Worker[] workers; 

... IOC stuff goes here ...

...some other methods ...

@override 
public void onSubmit( Command command ) {
  ... 
  /*I am dealing with 2 kind of objects and my problem is here */
 NewModelManyToManyObjectGoesHere wotgfc = (NewModelManyToManyObjectGoesHere) command;// 
 
  ... 
 } 

}
</code> 

Thanks very much I will try it out, thanks again.